# Abort mongooseJS save process inside doc.save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There's a way to abort the save process inside doc.save()?

```
doc.save(function (err) {
  if (ASD) {
    doc.abortProcess();
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer? No. But it sounds like you may want to take a look at validators – http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: Hi @jibsales, thanks to the answer! :) I imagine it. About validators, i really want what i asked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using invalidate();

```
if (this.isModified('_id')) {this.invalidate('_id', new Error('It's cannot be changed!'));}
```